# How to refactor this condition without using if else

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

Hi I have following code :

```
const handleChange = ({ selectedItem }) => {

    if (selectedItem?.value) {
      if (name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion1) {
        resetField(FieldNames.FirstAnswer, '');
        resetField(FieldNames.ConfirmFirstAnswer, '');
      } else if (name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion2) {
        resetField(FieldNames.SecondAnswer, '');
        resetField(FieldNames.ConfirmSecondAnswer, '');
      }
    }
  };
```

Here, I am trying to refactor this without using the if else and switch condition. So I tried with the ternary operator but it also does not work:

```
selectedItem?.value ? (name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion1) &&  resetField(FieldNames.FirstAnswer, '');
```

But this does not work as it is a wrong syntax. Can any one help me with this ?

Thanks.for the help.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to refactor your perfectly readable code into an illegible mess?

Comment: actually, it is adding a nested if else so that is the reason

Comment: Imo there is not that much to refactor, you could use a switch statement on the name but that's not really on optimization.

Comment: I'm all for reducing cyclomatic complexity, but replacing a nested `if` block with a nested ternary operator and some short-circuit boolean evaluation is not the way forward.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen can you give me a way with this boolean evaluation.

Comment: Do **NOT** abuse the ternary operator. If you need to do something like `let x = if (true) 10 else 20` then you should use the ternary operator because using `if` like that does not work. The ternary operator becomes the correct choice `let x = true ? 10 :20`. But if you don't use the result of the ternary operator you should refactor your code and replace the ternary operator with and `if` statement because: 1. It is the correct mechanism to use, 2. the syntax is much more structured and therefore less likely to cause bugs and 3. it is much easier to read

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend refactoring, because it's perfectly readable code and it seems to work fine, but I think this would solve your problem:

```
selectedItem?.value ? ((name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion1) &&  resetField(FieldNames.FirstAnswer, '')):null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to avoid nested ifs, why not put it in this way?

```
const handleChange = ({ selectedItem }) => {

    if (!selectedItem?.value) {
        return;
    }

    if (name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion1) {
        resetField(FieldNames.FirstAnswer, '');
        resetField(FieldNames.ConfirmFirstAnswer, '');
    } else if (name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion2) {
        resetField(FieldNames.SecondAnswer, '');
        resetField(FieldNames.ConfirmSecondAnswer, '');
    }
};
```

or this:

```
const handleChange = ({ selectedItem }) => {    

    if (selectedItem?.value && name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion1) {
        resetField(FieldNames.FirstAnswer, '');
        resetField(FieldNames.ConfirmFirstAnswer, '');
    } else if (selectedItem?.value && name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion2) {
        resetField(FieldNames.SecondAnswer, '');
        resetField(FieldNames.ConfirmSecondAnswer, '');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I can recommend refactoring your code that way but... since you ask, here is a way to do it without if/else/switch.

```
const condition0 = selectedItem?.value;
const condition1 = name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion1;
const condition2 = name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion2;

const doThen = () => {
  resetField(FieldNames.FirstAnswer, '');
  resetField(FieldNames.ConfirmFirstAnswer, '');
};

const doElse = () => {
  resetField(FieldNames.SecondAnswer, '');
  resetField(FieldNames.ConfirmSecondAnswer, '');
};

condition0 && (
  !(condition1 && (doThen() || true))
  && condition2 && doElse()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are refactoring the wrong thing. Obviously you are looking at your code and see that it is a bit of a mess with two places where the code seem to be repeated but not quite:

```
  if (name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion1) {
    resetField(FieldNames.FirstAnswer, '');
    resetField(FieldNames.ConfirmFirstAnswer, '');
  } else if (name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion2) {
    resetField(FieldNames.SecondAnswer, '');
    resetField(FieldNames.ConfirmSecondAnswer, '');
  }
```

Realise that the ternary operator is just an `if` in expression context instead of a statement. Converting it will result in exactly the same mess with less readable syntax.

If you **REALLY** want to know the correct ternary expression for the code you have it looks exactly the same:

```
selectedItem?.value ?
  name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion1 ?
    resetField(FieldNames.FirstAnswer, '')
    :
    resetField(FieldNames.ConfirmFirstAnswer, '')
  :
  name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion2 ?
    resetField(FieldNames.SecondAnswer, '')
    :
    resetField(FieldNames.ConfirmSecondAnswer, '');
```

The above is the correct way to **abuse** the ternary operator and get the same result. However, notice that it is still the same code and the same mess. And if you put the `:` in the wrong place it would be a bug and produce the wrong result!! The braces `{}` used by the `if` statement makes understanding and debugging the code much easier because it clarifies when a condition starts and when it ends.

The way to refactor this is to realize that `Question1` and `Question2` have common data. So structure it that way:

```
const FieldNames = {
    Security: {
        First: {
            Question: '...',
            Answer: '...',
            Confirm: '...'
        },
        Second: {
            Question: '...',
            Answer: '...',
            Confirm: '...'
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can refactor it like this:

```
const handleChange = ({ selectedItem }) => {
    if (selectedItem?.value) {
      for (let f of ['First', 'Second']) {
        if (name === FieldNames.Security[f].Question) {
            resetField(FieldNames.Security[f].Answer, '');
            resetField(FieldNames.Security[f].Confirm, '');
        }
      }
    }
};
```

This reduces duplicated code and makes your code DRY (and hence more compact) without reducing readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const handleChange = ({ selectedItem }) => {
  const answerIndex = selectedItem?.value ? (name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion1 ? 'FirstAnswer' : name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion2 ? 'SecondAnswer' : null) : null;
  if (answerIndex) {
    resetField(FieldNames[answerIndex], '');
    resetField(FieldNames[`Confirm${answerIndex}`], '');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleChange = ({ selectedItem }) => {

   if (selectedItem?.value && name === FieldNames.SecurityQuestion1) {
        resetField(FieldNames.FirstAnswer, '');
        resetField(FieldNames.ConfirmFirstAnswer, '');
   }
   if (selectedItem?.value && FieldNames.SecurityQuestion2) {
        resetField(FieldNames.SecondAnswer, '');
        resetField(FieldNames.ConfirmSecondAnswer, '');
   }

};
```

This is how I imagine a YouTuber I've seen who didn't like `else` statements would do it and addresses  you concerns about the nested `if/else` statement.

<opinion> I rather think it's an improvement in terms of clarity and maintainability but as to whether it's the best way to set up the code - no comment. </opinion>